# How to edit repository in GitHub?

Tags: arrays, .net

I am using it for the first time, so i need support.

I just tried to create it, but it didn't work.

So, please give me suggestion and help how to do it.

I need the best easy way to do it, and  faster way this is an important one to me.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably make yourself familiar with how git works. Git is a collaboration and version control tool to manage your source code. GitHub has a documentation that also contains a section which provides useful links to learn git: https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/quickstart/git-and-github-learning-resources

A small summary of what you need to do is:

At first, you will need to create a repository on GitHub. After signing in, you can create one by clicking the "+" button in the upper right.

Then, open a terminal and navigate to the folder where you want to have your code files in. Clone the repository into this folder using git:

```
git clone <github-repo-url>
```

see: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone

As you seem to be a beginner, it may be helpful to use a git tool that provides a GUI: https://git-scm.com/downloads/guis

Finally, you can create and edit your code files in that folder. You can also create subfolders. In order to sync your workspace with the origin repository, you will need to use `git-add` and `git-commit`.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is how to EDIT a repo, right? So I am assuming you have already created a repo.

## If not,

Step 1: Create your repo with this + sign and create the repository.

[image]

Step 2: Provide a unique name, If you want to add a README.md file click on the check box right next to it.

Step 3: Your empty repo is created.

Step 4: Install Git and open the terminal/Command prompt.

Step 5: Use cd command to navigate to the proper directory

Step 6: Clone the repo to your local PC,

```
git clone <your repo URL>
```

example:
[image]

```
c:\user\>git clone https://github.com/username/yourrepo.git
```

Step 7: Use any editor, to write your code. Save the files.

## else,

if you want to post the change or the code you have added to your repo, i.e make changes to your repository.

Step 8: Open command prompt,
Git command to post the changes on github from your local PC.

```
git add .
```

. signify preparing all the files for staging.

```
git commit -m "some message"

git push origin
```

And its done.